# DialogflowSDK middleware return after resolving a promise

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm currently playing around with the `actions-on-google` node sdk and I'm struggling to work out how to wait for a promise to resolve in my middleware before it then executes my intent. I've tried using `async/await` and returning a `promise` from my middleware function but neither method appears to work. I know typically you wouldn't override the intent like i'm doing here but this is to test what's going on.

```
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

function promiseTest() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Resolved');
        }, 2000)
    })
}
app.middleware(async (conv) => {
    let r = await promiseTest();
    conv.intent = r
})

    app.fallback(conv => {
    const intent = conv.intent;

    conv.ask("hello, you're intent was " + intent );
});
```

It looks like I should at least be able to return a `promise` https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/dialogflow.dialogflowmiddleware.html

but I'm not familiar with typescript so I'm not sure if I'm reading these docs correctly.

anyone able to advise how to do this correctly? For instance a real life sample might be I need to make a DB call and wait for that to return in my middleware before proceeding to the next step.

My function is using the NodeJS V8 beta in google cloud functions.

The output of this code is whatever the actual intent was e.g the default welcome intent, rather than "resolved" but there are no errors. So the middleware fires, but then moves onto the fallback intent before the promise resolves. e.g before setting `conv.intent = r`

Comment: What's the output of this code?

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov updated. But basically there's no error, it just fires the fallback intent. If I set `conv.intent` to another value before the await promise statement it does set it and then prints it out correctly when it falls into the fallback intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my issue was to do with an outdated version of the actions-on-google sdk. The dialogflow firebase example was using v2.0.0, changing this to 2.2.0 in the package.json resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Async stuff is really fiddly with the V2 API. And for me only properly worked with NodeJS 8. The reason is that from V2 onwards, unless you return the promise, the action returns empty as it has finished before the rest of the function is evaluated. There is a lot to work through to figure it out, here's some sample boilerplate I have that should get you going:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {BasicCard, MediaObject, Card, Suggestion, Image, Button} = require('actions-on-google');
var http_request = require('request-promise-native');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function handleMyIntent(agent) {
      let conv = agent.conv();
      let key = request.body.queryResult.parameters['MyParam'];
      var myAgent = agent;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http_request('http://someurl.com').then(async function(apiData) {
          if (key === 'Hey') {
            conv.close('Howdy');
          } else {
            conv.close('Bye');
          }
          myAgent.add(conv);
          return resolve();
      }).catch(function(err) {
          conv.close('  \nUh, oh. There was an error, please try again later');
          myAgent.add(conv);
          return resolve();
      })})
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('myCustomIntent', handleMyIntent);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

A brief overview of what you need:

- you have to return the promise resolution.
- you have to use the 'request-promise-native' package for HTTP requests
- you have to upgrade your plan to allow for outbound HTTP requests (https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

Comment: So, I've played around a bit, and if I use code similar to yours with my promise in the `fallback` intent, I can manipulate the `conv` object as I do in my contrived example (merely overwriting the intent), however if I try to change this using middleware as in `app.middleware` this doesn't work. In fact returning the promise and then returning the resolve function actually causes the agent to stop working. The error is : `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'parsed' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:115:69)`